# Adding a property to entities class, how I can avoid writing all properties again?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have used Entity Framework and it generated some entity classes for me I want to add a property to one of them there are a lot fields and attribute inside it, when I am going to add property to entity class I have to make child class which is inherited from my entity class then I am usually write this and it works :

```
IList<newEntity> chid = (from m in db.Entity
                        select new newEntity
                        {
                          //rewrite all properties here
                          newAttribute = ConvertDate(n.date) //it is example I break it into steps and called some functions to fill new attribute
                        }).ToList();
```

My question is how I can avoid rewriting all attribute here it really make me bored to write some code I can just add a new property how I can do that?

Comment: Could you add the entity as a property of the anonymous class, rather than add the properties directly?

Comment: I am going to show result on page what is your mean? could you explain it more for me? you mean adding property to child so what is useful is that avoid some code or not?

Comment: is this database-first? because you can just update your model then..

Comment: the database is in the first step but I can get Enumerable first and then adding new attribute but my problem is how I can avoid some extra codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but usually the classes generated by the Entity Framework are partial classes(*), so you don't need to derive from them to add a property. You can add properties, methods etc by adding a class to your codebase with the same name and in the same namespace and then the two definitions are merged by the compiler:

```
partial class Entity
{
    public DateTime newAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

(*) depending on your code generator